# How to Animate Vibrating Bristles?

Tags: animation, motion-blur

Hello to anyone who may be able to help.

I am trying to animate a set of bristles to vibrate very fast, like 100 - 200 hertz for a clients project and all I can manage is to make them move back and forth frame by frame. I am sure I am missing something as even with motion blur it just doesn't look right.

The product is unreleased so I can't post the files but imagine electric toothbrush bristles, the bristles I am trying to animate below.[image: Bristles I am trying to get to vibrate]

Also halfway through this video is the effect I am trying to achieve [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4_MGFd2Sug[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4_MGFd2Sug%5BVideo) of toothbrush][2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4_MGFd2Sug)

Any help with this would be hugely appreciated as I'm really up against this with my client wanting to see results soon.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I have to do the same kind of animation.

Comment: See answer I posted :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did figure it out in the end.

Keyframe at frame 1 the object at the starting point, frame 2 keyframe off to the side and frame 3 back to the start.

In the graph editor get the modifiers from the"n" menu on the right and add a cycles modifier.

The speed of the vibration is tied to the framerate of the animation, so set a custom frame rate of 120 for 120 oscillations per second for example.

Hope this helps,

Oli

[image]